# How to create empty char arrays in Cython without loops

Tags: python, c, cython

Well, this seems easy, but I can't find a single reference on the web. In C we can create a `char` array of `n` null-characters as follows:

```
char arr[n] = "";
```

But when I try to do the same in Cython with

```
cdef char arr[n] = ""
```

I get this compilation error:

```
Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
cdef char a[n] = ""
                   ^
------------------------------------------------------------

Syntax error in C variable declaration
```

Obviously Cython doesn't allow to declare arrays this way, but is there an alternative? I don't want to manually set each item in the array, that is I'm not looking for something like this

```
cdef char a[10]
for i in range(0, 10, 1):
    a[i] = b"\0"
```

Comment: You're not getting `n` null characters. Also, where are your `;`s?

Comment: I've just tested it and I do get n `\0` characters in the C code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't have to set each element to make a length-zero C string. It is sufficient to just zero the first element:

```
cdef char arr[n]
arr[0] = 0
```

Next, if you want to zero the whole char array, use memset

```
from libc.string cimport memset
cdef char arr[n]
memset(arr, 0, n)
```

And if C purists complain about the 0 instead of '\0', note that the '\0' is a Python string (unicode in Python 3) in Cython. '\0' is not a C char in Cython! memset expects an integer value for its second argument, not a Python string.

If you really want to know the int value of a C '\0' in Cython, you must write a helper function in C:

```
/* zerochar.h */
static int zerochar() 
{
    return '\0';
}
```

And now:

```
cdef extern from "zerochar.h":
    int zerochar()

cdef char arr[n]
arr[0] = zerochar()
```

or

```
cdef extern from "zerochar.h":
    int zerochar()

from libc.string cimport memset
cdef char arr[n]
memset(arr, zerochar(), n)
```

Comment: Well, your answer is the closest to what I wished to get. I completely forgot about `memset`. Thank you a lot for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

In C '' is used for a char, and "" for a string. But any 'empty char' does not really make sense, probably what you want is '\0' or just 0

Maybe:

```
import cython
from libc.stdlib cimport malloc, free

cdef char * test():
    n = 10
    cdef char *arr = <char *>malloc(n * sizeof(char))

    for n in range(n):
        arr[n] = '\0'

    return arr
```

**Edit**

```
void *
 calloc(size_t count, size_t size);
```

Does that for you,

Comment: I told that I'm not looking for a way to do this manually (with loops).

Comment: Well you don't have much of a choice, if you do arr = "" then only arr[0] will be a \0, the rest will be filled with garbage that was there in memory before. The other answer provides a solution which is an implicit loop (python does it for you)  ['\0'] * n but it's a neat way to do it, also rather fast.

Comment: After all your answer made me recall `calloc`, that does the job in one line.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
cdef char *arr = ['\0']*n
```

Comment: I believe this creates a temporary Python list in memory which is slow and not good in general, since it harms the `nogil` semantics of pure C code in Cython. If it doesn't, I would gladly accept your answer.

Comment: I think more to the point, this answer a) doesn't compile (at least with recent versions of Cython) and b) if it did compile would create a pointer into a python object which promptly ceases to exist (which is why it doesn't compile)